# Macro, automatically adding one to a value

Tags: macros, notepad++, auto-increment

I have a problem with macro in notepad++

Just needs to have value automatically changed to +1 (from current value)

So the values should be like this 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003 and so on for the coming values between the MEDIA_ID tags..

```
      <MEDIA>
      <MEDIA_ID>1000</MEDIA_ID>
      </MEDIA>
      <MEDIA>
      <MEDIA_ID>1001</MEDIA_ID>
      </MEDIA>
```

I have no idea how do this..

Could anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: What's the usage?  You need to do this regularly?  A one-off need?  You could definitely do this using PythonScript and FingerText; but to what extent is it needed?  Do inserts in the middle of the list need to adjust lower entries or are they always at the bottom and always sorted?

Answer (score 6):

1) Generate the list of numbers from 1000 to the number you want using excel and copy this into notepad++.

2) Go to the start of the file.

3) Start the macro recorder.

```
4) type <MEDIA>(down arrow)(HOME button)<MEDIA_ID>(END button)</MEDIA>(down arrow)(HOME button)</MEDIA>(down arrow)(HOME button)
```

5) repeat this macro as many times as needed.

Answer (score 4):

If you can align the tags vertically then you might be able to use the `Column Editor` to do the numbering. Say you format the XML like this:

```
<MEDIA><MEDIA_ID></MEDIA_ID></MEDIA>
<MEDIA><MEDIA_ID></MEDIA_ID></MEDIA>
....
<MEDIA><MEDIA_ID></MEDIA_ID></MEDIA>
```

Now, place your cursor betweeen the start and end tags of `MEDIA_ID`. Choose `Column Editor...` from the `Edit` menu (ALT+C keyboard shortcut). Change the radio button to `Number to Insert` with a starting value of 1001 incrementing by 1 (Decimal). Confirm using the OK button. You should end up with this:

```
<MEDIA><MEDIA_ID>1001</MEDIA_ID></MEDIA>
<MEDIA><MEDIA_ID>1002</MEDIA_ID></MEDIA>
....
<MEDIA><MEDIA_ID>1199</MEDIA_ID></MEDIA>
```

Sadly, it seems that this operations cannot be used in a macro. But maybe it helps.